# How to merge mongodb query results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

So I have an AR model that looks like this (all strings and date attributes):

AR
driver_id
driver_name
driver_license
paid_on (date)
...
helper_id
helper_name
helper_license
paid_on_helper (date)

I have this query to show unpaid

```
    def self.unpaid
        result1 = AR.where(:paid_on => nil).in(:status => [AR::TRANSACTION_COMPLETE,AR::CANCELLED_BY_REQUESTER]).gt(:total_owed_to_driver => 0).asc(:assigned_driver_id).asc(:timestamp_requested)
        result2 = AR.where(:paid_on_helper => nil, :assigned_driver2_id.ne => nil).in(:status => [AR::TRANSACTION_COMPLETE,AR::CANCELLED_BY_REQUESTER]).gt(:total_owed_to_driver => 0).asc(:assigned_driver2_id).asc(:timestamp_requested)
        result1.to_a.concat(result2.to_a)
        result1
      end
```

The issue is that when I merge the two this way I end up with an array like this.

```
    Joe (main driver)
    Joe (main driver)
    Joe (main driver)
    Bob (main driver)
    Bob (main driver)
    Larry (main driver)
    Larry (main driver)
    Larry (main driver)
    Joe (2nd driver)
    Joe (2nd driver)
    Bob (2nd driver)
    Bob (2nd driver)
    Bob (2nd driver)
    Bob (2nd driver)
    Larry (2nd driver)
    Larry (2nd driver)
```

What I need is an array that ends like this.

```
    Joe (main driver)
    Joe (main driver)
    Joe (main driver)
    Joe (2nd driver)
    Joe (2nd driver)
    Bob (main driver)
    Bob (main driver)
    Bob (2nd driver)
    Bob (2nd driver)
    Bob (2nd driver)
    Bob (2nd driver)
    Larry (main driver)
    Larry (main driver)
    Larry (main driver)
    Larry (2nd driver)
    Larry (2nd driver)
```

I am guessing its a sorting combined with a secondary or tertiary where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this be accomplished using a single mongo query? Something like this:

```
def self.unpaid
  AR.or({ :paid_on => nil }, { :paid_on_helper => nil, :assigned_driver2_id.ne => nil })
    .in(:status => [AR::TRANSACTION_COMPLETE,AR::CANCELLED_BY_REQUESTER])
    .gt(:total_owed_to_driver => 0)
    .asc(:assigned_driver_id)
    .asc(:timestamp_requested)
end
```

Comment: Tried this and when displaying in my erb, it only shows the the items that fall under this param (:paid_on_helper => nil, :assigned_driver2_id.ne => nil)

Comment: Try calling `.explain` on your query. This should show the actual mongo query and may help you debug.

Comment: I did and now my app is crashing. It will restart and then crash continuously. wtf?

Comment: Only use `.explain` in your Rails console, not your app code. For example: `bundle exec rails console`